# Export plain text (a header) to excel with c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, export-to-excel

Working with C#, Visual Studio 2008 & .NET Framework 3.5. I can export records directly from DataGridView to excel, the problem is that I need to export other data (plain text).

This is my excel now:

[image: Excel table without header]

And this is how I need to display the header (the rows on top of the table):

[image: excel with more info]

This is how I'm doing it now:

```
protected void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename=InformeEstudios.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    myGridView1.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
public override void  VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
     //base.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control);
}

//MY METHOD
private void BinData()
{
    SqlConnection conex = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xx.xxx.x.xx;Initial   
    Catalog=MYDATABASE;User ID=MYUSER;Password=MYPASS");
    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("select ROW1, ROW2 from MYTABLE", conex);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ad.Fill(ds);
    myGridView1.DataSource = ds;
    myGridView1.DataBind();
}
```

How can I accomplish this, **how can I wrote those two header rows manually**. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

control.RenderControl(...) is just outputting html.  So output your own html first.. then call rendercontrol.